# Admob ad hidden by WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, admob, helper

Recently, I have been trying to add `admob` into my app for the Google Play store.

I know that my ad is hidden under the `WebView`, because  when I remove the `WebView` code, I can see the ad. However, when I replace the `WebView`, the ad is hidden again. How can I keep the ad from being hidden?

Below is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private android.webkit.WebView mWebview;
private Toast toast;
private long lastBackPressTime = 0L;
int dar = 0;
private ProgressDialog mDialog;
private Menu mymenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "U5N|tech, loading...", true);
    mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebview = new android.webkit.WebView(this);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);// enable javascript
    final Activity activity = this;
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.dismiss();

            String webUrl = mWebview.getUrl();

        }

    });

    mWebview.loadUrl("http://yousif.u5n.co.uk/dictionaryapp");


    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // don't touch anything above this line

    setContentView(mWebview);

     //loads webpages in webview instead of launching browser

}
```

Comment: Your webview is probably on top of your adview. Post your layout.

Comment: <WebView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
 android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
         >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>